# Page refresh without reloading a page and calling external files in php ajax

Tags: php, ajax

I have a profile page where im showing the friends of that user from db, I'm using auto scroller that works fine if I place that data directly in main file not an external file, Also I have a drop down that on selection will sort the friends records accordingly, but as I have moved the code to main file, I need to make ajax call to same file not an external, to repopulate data with required sorting.

Please let me know how can i do this on same file with ajax. On selection of drop down value.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using Jquery?

Its surprisingly easy. You just need to do $('#contentdiv').load('contentyouwant') where you bind the  event for the ddl.

Comment: i cannot do like this as my scroller does not work then, I have made a php function to populate the data, and made a switch case statement based on arguments to call function, now i just need to know what ajax code i can use to reload my page by passing the arg so case may use this arg and call appropriate function, is there a way in ajax that i can call my page with new arguments without reload.

Comment: Actually, I have used your proposed solution for external files. It was working fine. But now I just need to call the same page with new args but not to reload it. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

If you must use the same file, place the code that will be ran by ajax, in a function. then at the beginning of the page, evaluate if this was the ajax call or the whole file.

Hope it helps.

Comment: can you put example for that plz?

Comment: I will need to create an example of your code to show you, is it possible to supply your code, and let me edit it?

Comment: It is an example of scroller http://testingreferredbydoctor.info/scrol/, i have to use this in my profile page to show user friends, Previously I was using <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript">
function getcontent(path)
{
       $(function() {
         $("#content").load(path)
       })
}
</script><div id="content"></div>

Comment: in path i was giving the external file for populating friends. Now i need to use this in main file as my scroller not work as a external file. Actually I have header, footer, main content all in separate files so its difficult to show you the code. Please try to give some example that loads the page content but not reloads the page.

Comment: since i don't have your php code... 
I assume you retrieve your data from a sql database, 
put in a where clause that filer based on your dropdown selection, 
and if there is no dropdown selection ignore where clause. 
When your dropdown changes reload page with dropdown selection variable passed.

Comment: yes im doing so, but on dropdown selection I dont want to reload, its for filtering the data from db

Comment: i cannot show you where to change your code without your code. i don't have a good example to show in your coding style. I will need your full php script that generate this page.